# Send To/Mail Recipient from WSH

Tags: email, wsh

I am trying to implement in windows scripting host the same function as windows Send To/Mail Recipient does. Did not find anything usefull on google except steps to instantiate `Outlook.Application` and directly calling its methods.

I need to go the same path as windows do, as there is a mix of Outlook and Lotus Notes installed, I don't see it good to perform some sort of testing and deciding which object to talk to...

What I have found is that the actual work is done by `sendmail.dll`, there is a handler defined in registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9E56BE60-C50F-11CF-9A2C-00A0C90A90CE}`. I would like either to use this dll somehow or to simulate the same steps it does.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one item on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/sendtomail.aspx) from 2003 that might be relevant.

Comment: Although I don't need this anymore, the CodeProject article would probably help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the sent to menu in Windows is a bunch of files (usually links) in the C:\Documents and Settings\username\SendTo folder. You need to add your script - or a link to it - there.

For your script you could check if certain registry keys exist to detect Outlook and Lotus Notes.

Or if you don't care if the message shows up in sent items, just use CDOSYS.NewMail to send the message directly to the SMTP-server.

[CDOSYS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505938.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Adding items to SendTo folder was not the point of question. Also I really don't want to implement twice (Outlook and Notes).